# Better recursive loop in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3.2. Let's say I want 2 options:

1. Get all trip photos.
2. Get the first trip photo.

I have the following code:

```
# trip.rb
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trip_days

  def trip_photos
    if (photos = trip_days.map(&:spots).flatten.map(&:photos).flatten.map)
      photos.each do |photo|
        photo.url(:picture_preview)
      end
    end 
  end

  def trip_photo
    trip_photos.first
  end
end

# trip_day.rb
class TripDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  has_many :trip_day_spots
  has_many :spots, :through => :trip_day_spots
end

# trip_day_spot.rb
class TripDaySpot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip_day
  belongs_to :spot
end

#spot.rb
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# trips_controller.rb
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  def index    
    @trips = Trip.public.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
  end
end
```

As expected, the `trip_photos` method generates lots of SQL query. I wonder if there is any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, but to eager load, just add `:include`:

```
# trips_controller.rb
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  def index    
    @trips = Trip.public.paginate(:include => [:trip_days => [:spots => :photos]], :page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of N+1 queries. In this cases, we need to eager load all the associations of base object, so that when ever you call its associated object, it wont fire any queries for fetching them, simply it will get them from its cached object.

Hope this will work, but not tested. I assumed and wrote the following query.

```
def trip_photos
  user_trip_days = trip_days.includes(:spots => :photos)
  photos = user_trip_days.collect {|trip_day| trip_day.spots.map(&:photos).flatten}.flatten
  photos.each do |photo|
    photo.url(:picture_preview)
  end if photos
end
```

Let me know if you get any errors.

For more info on eager loading associated objects in ActiveRecord, go through

[Guides for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) and [Rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading) and [Rails Tips](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/6411587940/eager-loading)

Comment: Thanks. I got something like `#<photo:0x007ff723445ac40>` when running `trip_photo` via `trip_photos`, but haven't got the time to fix it because I am going out. It should return the `.url(:picture_preview`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most rails-y way, but if you truly wanted to get all the spots in one hit you could do something like:

```
def spots
 Spot.joins("join trip_days_spots on spots.id = trip_days_spots.spot_id join trip_days on trip_days.id = trip_days_spots.trip_day_id join trips on trips.id = trip_days.trip_id").where("trips.id = ?", self.id)
end
```

then change your loop to:

```
def trip_photos
  spots.map(&:photos).flatten.each do |photo|
    photo.url(:picture_preview)
  end
end
```